# even after I import my jsx file to page.js file, the error is module not found, how do I solve this?(vscode)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created a mysec.jsx file under components of src, also used export func. and in page.js file i have used the import func. but the error is---> Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/mysec.jsx'
1 | import Image from 'next/image';

> 2 | import mysec from '../components/mysec.jsx';
> 3 |
> 4 |
> 5 | export default function Home() {

i have made sure it is in the correct directory, no error in the program and also restarted the dev window several times.

Comment: Is the issue with mysec.jsx or with the import Image statment (presumably inside of mysec.jsx)? Might be helpful to include at least the top section of the code for both page.js and mysec.jsx.

Answer (score 1):

you should rename mysec.jsx with capital like Mysec.jsx and the function and the export also and don't type the extension with the import like this

```
import Mysec from '../components/Mysec';
```

it should works